# учитывать только последнюю цифру числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто знает как в условии учитывать только последнюю цифру числа?
Например 10, учитываем только 0, 20 только 0, число 34 учитываем только 4? Есть такая функция в питоне?

Comment: Это называется деление по модулю или остаток от деления: `n % 10` - делает именно то, что вам надо

Comment: А для `-12` - что следует вернуть? а для `2.5`?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. По синтаксису не подскажете? Как записать такое условие: 
if $a == второму числу из цифры.
____выполняем условие.

Можно ли записать так:
if $a == n % 10:
____выполняем условие.

Comment: $a... платная переменная из php? )) можно, берите второе ([1]) число и сравнивайте с а...

Comment: @Василий добавил в ответ

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

Это называется деление по модулю или остаток от деления: n % 10 - делает именно то, что вам надо:

Примеры:

```
In [1]: 10 % 10
Out[1]: 0

In [2]: 20 % 10
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: 834756 % 10
Out[3]: 6
```

Также существует удобная функция [divmod(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#divmod), возвращающая кортеж из двух чисел - результат **целочисленного** деления `a` на `b` (`a // b`) и остаток от деления `a` на `b` (`a % b`).

Примеры:

```
In [4]: divmod(123, 10)
Out[4]: (12, 3)

In [5]: divmod(876, 10)
Out[5]: (87, 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно перевести число в строку, взять последний символ и перевести снова в число:

```py
>>> a = 42
>>> b = 1000
>>> c = 12345
>>> d = -12
>>> e = 0.123

>>> print(int(str(a)[-1]))
2
>>> print(int(str(b)[-1]))
0
>>> print(int(str(c)[-1]))
5
>>> print(int(str(d)[-1]))
2
>>> print(int(str(e)[-1]))
3
```

**UPD** "Как записать такое условие: if a == второму числу из цифры. ____выполняем условие. Можно ли записать так: `if a == n % 10`"

Нет, `n % 10` - только последняя цифра в неотрицательном целом числе

Чтобы оперировать любой цифрой в числе, можно написать функцию, которая на вход принимает число и номер нужной цифры и вернет ее (игнорируя знаки минус и точки для чисел с плавающей запятой):

```py
get_digit(number, count):
    number_list = [x for x in str(number) if x.isdigit()]
    return int(number_list[count])
```

и использовать в коде:

```py
pi = 3.14159265359
count = 1  # индекс цифры в числе, начиная с 0, т.е. тут - вторая цифра в pi

if a == get_digit(pi, count):
    # do something
```