# 1 число числа 0

Tags: python

как сделать чтобы в этом коде не вылетала ошибка

```
a = 0
print (a[-1])
```

могу я как то сделать так чтобы выводилось 1 число нуля?

Comment: Нельзя, число не является ни списком, ни словарём, ни чем-то ещё подобным, и операция получения элемента по индексу на нём не реализована и бессмысленна

Comment: Только если преобразовать в строку: `a = "0"`

Comment: @Павел если `a` будет меньше нуля или больше девяти, результат будет странный)

Comment: `print(str(a)[-1])`.

Comment: @andreymal а возможно перевести из числа в строчное значение чтобы выводилось?

Comment: @playMaster ну вот выше в комментах варианты уже предложили, только лично я не понял что вообще такое «1 число нуля»

Comment: @andreymal а почему странным? не понял вас

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.  @andreymal у меня большой код не получиться обьяснить зачем мне это нужно.

Comment: Ну тогда «Закрыть → Непонятна суть вопроса»

Comment: Ну или возможный дубликат вопроса: [учитывать только последнюю цифру числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229775/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) (впрочем, там формулировка тоже не сильно лучше)

Answer (score -2):

```
print(str(a)[-1])
```

a не является не списком и нечем поэтому этот код реализует число a в строчное значение